# Photovoltaics: maximum gain per square meter using current technology

Tags: solar-cell

As far as photovoltaic (as in solar panels) is concerned, there are monocrystal, polycrystal and concentrated panel devices available (as far as i know). There may be some more detailed nuances and/or future variants in the technologies, but I am not aware of these (enlighten me!)

I live in central Europe and I'm **looking for technology that would yield the maximum possible gain** (be it in Watt-peaks or in kWh).
According to [this source](http://www.greenrhinoenergy.com/solar/radiation/empiricalevidence.php), some 1200 kWh per square meter per year are available in this location.

So, what specific technology would you recommend for maximum possible gain per square meter?
Is it worth to implement such a technology now, or would it be wiser to wait some ten years or so for a more effective technology to become available?
(note that the concentrated photovoltaic variant is probably out of question for my location, since this requires hard, focused light (no clouds in the sky, etc.))

Comment: kWh is not a unit of power.

Comment: @OlinLathrop the referenced chart is actually in kilowatt-hours per square meter _per year_.

Comment: @Phil: The question still needs to be correct on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Multi-junction cells have the highest theoretical efficiency](http://www.gizmag.com/nrl-solar-cell-50-percent-conversion/25826/), but I believe that almost everybody installing solar on the domestic scale is using whatever has the best cost/watt value. Multi-junction cells are much more expensive and less available.

[It looks like poly and monocrystalline are comparable,](http://www.solarchoice.net.au/blog/monocrystalline-vs-polycrystalline-solar-panels-busting-myths/) depending on exact manufacturer.